# How to export Whatsapp chat into a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart, whatsapp

I have tried using the WhatsApp share plugin, which helps export WhatsApp chat.
But it just doesn't work.
I am trying to export the chats but the app doesn't respond to the share intent.
If we export the chat somewhere else and then use the .txt file to share to my app it works.
How can I solve this.

Comment: Please show the relevant code to make this a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check [receive_whatsapp_chat](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_whatsapp_chat) package

It enables flutter apps to receive chats from WhatsApp and it is working for both Android and IOS.

[image: android_example]
[image: ios_example]

Example:

```
@override
void receiveChatContent(ChatContent chatContent) {
  // TODO: implement receiveChatContent
}
```